# Geb - How to interrogate Page Request Parameters

Tags: grails, geb

I have a Grails Cucumber test, using Geb.

How do I get the request parameters defined for the current page?

E.g. Given the current page url is `www.foo.com/list?sort=name&order=asc`

How do I test what the values for the `sort` and `order` params are?

Comment: Do you want to get current request parameters of the page browser is at?

Comment: @erdi - Yes, I'm trying to inspect the request parameters for the current page.  I have tried using page.getDriver().getCurrentUrl() but that was not returning the parameters.  However, I'm not sure if the URL has been changed correctly (I'm trying to click on a column heading to sort).

Comment: it's browser.driver.currentUrl and then you would need to extract parameters from the url yourself or using a library

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get hold of the current URL in the browser (including parameters):

Use:

```
def url = browser.driver.currentUrl
```

Or (if you are using the Page object pattern)

```
def url = page.driver.currentUrl
```

Then you can use URIBuilder to extract the query parameters:

Import the HTTPBuilder module by adding the following to BuildConfig.groovy under the dependencies section:

```
test 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.5.2'
```

Extract the url paramters using:

```
def builder = new URIBuilder(url);
assert 'name' == builder.query.sort;
assert 'asc' == builder.query.order;
```

Thanks to @erdi for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

//add this on the list controller

## which will be executed right before any controller action is loaded.

```
def beforeIntereseptor {

def myUrl = request.request.requestURL  // to get all 
//or
def myUrl = request.request.requestURL.getParameter("ref") 
 /* "request.request.requestURL" don't get the desired URL */     
//do soemthing based on your url then

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without affecting the application code?  I'd prefer not to expose test fixtures to the application.

Comment: where do you want it ,you can using your browser ?